# Is it possible to make http requests with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, httprequest

Is it possible to make http requests with MATLAB?

I am specifically interested in the way to make a request and store the response as a new variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try starting with the functions `urlread` and `web`.

Answer (score 1):

[`urlread`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/urlread.html) will make an HTTP request to any URL and return the results as a char array.

For example:

```
>> s = urlread('http://www.mathworks.com');
>> whos s
  Name      Size               Bytes  Class    Attributes

  s         1x23346            46692  char
```

Depending on exactly what you're looking to extract as a variable, you may have to further post-process the result using functions like [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/regexp.html) and [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/str2double.html).

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions?! Oh dear God NOOOOOO!!! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) ... Seriously though, this isn't such a terrible option for simple parsing conditions. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use matlab.net.http

```
header = [matlab.net.http.field.AcceptField(matlab.net.http.MediaType('application/json'))...
    matlab.net.http.field.ContentTypeField('text/plain');];
body = jsonencode(data);
request = matlab.net.http.RequestMessage(matlab.net.http.RequestMethod.POST,...
    header,...
    body);
response = send(request, self.address);
result = response.Body.Data;
```